# How can I monitor for bot accounts accessing drupal paths without permission?

Tags: security

On my site, users do not have permission to create content.

However, looking through the watchdog logs, I found several accounts that were attempting to access

```
node/add/article
node/add/page
```

and so on.  In this case, all the accounts were registered from *@ad.drupaler.org*, so it was easy to eliminate them, but in case the same thing happens from a variety of domains in the future, I'd like to set up some way to alert myself that users are attempting to access these paths.

I am thinking about using the Rules module to do this, but I was wondering if there was already a "best practice" for this kind of thing-- since there are automated bots to attack Drupal sites, there might be an automated way to fight back.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding bot protection to your registration form,

e.g with [reCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha)

Other worthwhile things are blocking the bots in your webserver,

e.g nginx

- https://github.com/mariusv/nginx-badbot-blocker or
- https://github.com/oohnoitz/nginx-blacklist/blob/master/blacklist.conf

Custom options include using the Flood control API,

e.g [`flood_is_allowed`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/flood_is_allowed/7) and [`flood_register_event`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/flood_register_event/7) with ip blocking (e.g [`system_ip_blocking_form_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_ip_blocking_form_submit/7)) or [`user_block_user_action`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_block_user_action/7) on the node/add or 403 page.